# В консоли работает, вставляю в пхп код-ошибки, дело в кавычках?

Tags: javascript, php

```
echo '<script>document.getElementById('auth-danger').innerHTML = "<p class='auth-error text-danger ml-4'>.text-dangerrrr</p>";</script>';
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё дело в экранировании элементов.
Воспользуйтесь следующим вариантом:

```php
<?php
?>
<div id="auth-danger"></div>
<?php
echo "<script>document.getElementById('auth-danger').innerHTML = '<p class=`auth-error text-danger ml-4`>.text-dangerrrr</p>';</script>";
```

Второй вариант:

```php
<?php
?>
<div id="auth-danger"></div>
<?php
echo "<script>document.getElementById('auth-danger').innerHTML = '<p class=\'auth-error text-danger ml-4\'>.text-dangerrrr</p>';</script>";
```

Скрин выполнения обоих вариантов одинаковый:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Либо `\'` экранировать кавычки

Comment: не помогло, в консоли выдаёт Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: суть в том, что у меня в другом файле пустой контейнер и мне при определеном условии нужно создать в этом контейнере текст в <p> </p>

Comment: если вставляю свой код из вопроса в консоль, то всё ок. А если вставляю его в echo уже не работает

Comment: @user366600 Это потому что `echo` У Вас добавляет ещё ковычек. Добавил ещё вариант. Оба варианта у меня работают.

Comment: @user366600 Не забудьте убедиться, что у Вас есть поле с нужным классом, в который Вы хотите вставить элемент.

Comment: почему при загрузке страницы он сразу выдает ошибку в консоли , мол, Cannot set property 'innerHTML' , хотя до выполнения этого участка кода(когда вызывается echo) я еще не дошел ?

Comment: @user366600 Создайте новый файл - скопируйте мой ответ и попробуйте запустить. Скорее всего у Вас просто нет элемента с таким `id`.

Comment: он есть, ведь если запускать js код через консоль, то всё ок

Comment: похоже на то, что Ваш ответ правильньный, но почему-то у меня не работает...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104761/discussion-between-denis640kb-and-user366600).